# Swift ObjectMapper loop in nested

Tags: swift

I have this mapper:

```
import Foundation
import ObjectMapper

class Article: Mappable {
    var id: Int!
    var name: String!
    var image: String!
    var children: Article!

    required init?(_ map: Map) {
        mapping(map)
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {
        id <- map["id"]
        name <- map["name"]
        image <- map["image"]
        children <- map["children"]
    }
}
```

and then i need to loop and find article by id:

```
func getArticleName(aid) {
    for article in articleList {
        if aid == article.id {
            return article.name
        }
        for child in article.children {
            if aid == child.id {
                return child.name
            }
        }
    }
    return ""
}
```

`articleList` is array of that `Article` mappable class.

Now when i loop in children, i get this error:

`Value of type 'Article' has no member 'Generator'`

How can i loop in children array?

Comment: What's the question? Do you not understand that error message?

Comment: Yes, and how can i loop in children array?

Comment: It's not an array. That's what the error message is telling you.

Comment: Ohhh, my bad, forgot `[]`, thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what ObjectMapper is, but the error message is simple enough. You are saying:

```
class Article: Mappable {
    var children: Article!
}
```

Thus, an article's `children` is an Article. So then when you say:

```
for child in article.children {
```

...the compiler stops you; an Article, which is what the `children` is, is not something about which you can say `for ... in`.